# Run two scripts at the same time

Tags: shell, scripting, parallelism

I want to run two scripts at the same time. How exactly do I do this?

If I have a variable called `foo` in `script1` and change its value to 5, and if I'm using a variable with the same name in `script2` (that runs simultaneously with `script1`), will the value of variable `foo` in `script2` also become 5?

Answer (score 2):

You could run the first script in background like this:

```
skript1 & skript2
```

Each script will run as a separate process. You cannot change variables in the other script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open up two separate `screen` sessions to run both scripts. For example:

```
screen -S sampleOne
./runScript.sh
```

At that point you would hold CTRL+A&D, which will exit the screen without terminating and then type:

```
screen -S sampleTwo
./runScript2.sh
```

One other way would be to use `tmux` to do this as well:

```
tmux new-window -a -n SampleWindows
tmux new-session -d -s SampleWindows -n SSH0 -d
tmux selectp -t SampleWindows
tmux bind-key -n M-Left previous-window -t SampleWindows
tmux bind-key -n M-Right next-window -t SampleWindows
tmux new-window -n sampleOne -t SampleWindows
tmux new-window -n sampleTwo -t SampleWindows
tmux send-keys -t SampleWindows:0 './sampleScript' C-m
tmux send-keys -t SampleWindows:1 './sampleScript2.sh' C-m
tmux attach -t WinSplit
```